# Delete vote count does not update unless I refresh the page

Tags: bug, voting

I was recently looking through answers with delete votes in the 10k tools and found a question with two answers that needed to be deleted. I clicked the delete button on the first one, and it informed me that I had 14 remaining. I proceeded to cast my vote, and then clicked delete on the second answer and it also informed me that I had 14 votes remaining. I refreshed the page and it updated to show I only had 13 votes remaining.